# Android build failed re: A problem occurred evaluating project ':unimodules-react-native-adapter'

Tags: android, react-native, expo, build.gradle

I have my React Native *(Expo SDK38 detached app)* project fully built and functioning properly for iOS. I'm now working to get it set for Android. I've downloaded Android Studio and installed the proper Java versions etc. for my Mac, but I still can't get my project to build. Here's my most recent error...

`cd android && ./gradlew :app:dependencies`

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

*What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':unimodules-react-native-adapter'.*

> Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':unimodules-react-native-adapter:classpath' after it has been resolved.

Note: earlier I'd tried installing Jetifier re: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25483#issuecomment-508446776 but that didn't seem to help at all

Edit: When attempting to run through Android Studio, this is the error I am seeing...

*Could not determine the dependencies of task ':expo-permissions:compileDebugAidl'.*

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':expo-permissions:debugCompileClasspath'.